# Cómo desdoblar una columna haciendo referencia a dos otras variables en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Tengo las dos siguientes tablas:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tb_team (
    team_code CHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    team_alias VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    country_code CHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    coach_name VARCHAR (120) NOT NULL,
    association_name VARCHAR (100),
    first_captain_name VARCHAR (120) NOT NULL,
    group_name VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    created_by_user VARCHAR (10) DEFAULT ('OS_UEFA') NOT NULL,
    created_date DATE,
    updated_date DATE,
    CONSTRAINT pk_tb_team PRIMARY KEY (team_code),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tb_team FOREIGN KEY (country_code) REFERENCES tb_country (country_code)
);


CREATE TABLE tb_match (
    home_team_code CHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    visitor_team_code CHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    match_date DATE NOT NULL,
    stadium_code CHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    referee_code CHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    phase_code INTEGER NOT NULL,
    home_goals INTEGER NOT NULL,
    visitor_goals INTEGER NOT NULL,
    home_cards INTEGER NOT NULL,
    visitor_cards INTEGER NOT NULL,
    created_by_user VARCHAR (10) DEFAULT ('OS_UEFA') NOT NULL,
    created_date DATE,
    updated_date DATE,
    CONSTRAINT pk_tb_match PRIMARY KEY (home_team_code, visitor_team_code, match_date),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tb_match FOREIGN KEY (home_team_code) REFERENCES tb_team (team_code),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tb_match1 FOREIGN KEY (visitor_team_code) REFERENCES tb_team (team_code),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tb_match2 FOREIGN KEY (stadium_code) REFERENCES tb_stadium (stadium_code),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tb_match3 FOREIGN KEY (referee_code) REFERENCES tb_referee (referee_code),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tb_match4 FOREIGN KEY (phase_code) REFERENCES tb_phase (phase_code)
);
```

Se me pide que obtenga una tabla con las columnas local (team_alias) y visitante (team_alias), el problema que tengo es que me muestra siempre el mismo team_alias.

```sql
SELECT team_alias AS local, team_alias AS visitante, referee_name AS arbitro, dob AS fecha_nacimiento
FROM tb_match
INNER JOIN tb_team
ON tb_match.visitor_team_code = tb_team.team_code
GROUP BY home_team_code, visitor_team_code, team_alias;
```

Un ejemplo de dos rows de la tabla tb_team:

| team_code | team_alias |
| --- | --- |
| T0001 | Die Mannschaft |
| T0013 | Los Magiares Magicos |

Luego tengo la tabla tb_match, dónde aparecen estos team_code, pero separados por equipos locales y visitantes, pongo un ejemplo:

| home_team_code | visitor_team_code |
| --- | --- |
| T0001 | T0013 |

El select que deberia conseguir es el siguiente:

| team_alias_local | team_alias_visitante |
| --- | --- |
| Die Mannschaft | Los Magiares Magicos |

Solo consigo que me devuelva el team_alias del local en las dos columnas..

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Deberías proporcionar datos de ejemplo (inserts en esas dos tablas) y resultados esperados (lo que tiene que devolver la select con esos datos de ejemplo). Con esas dos pequeñas aportaciones, seguro que hay más gente que te puede ayudar.

Comment: Gracias Carlos, proporciono ejemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Para hacer lo que pides, tienes que unir la tabla de equipos dos veces, una para el equipo local y otra para el equipo visitante. También te faltó incluir la tabla del referee. Para poder unir una tabla dos veces es indispensable usar alias para las tablas. También es buena idea usar los alias en todas tus consultas con más de una tabla para hacer más fácil la lectura y escritura del código.

```
SELECT l.team_alias   AS local, 
       v.team_alias   AS visitante, 
       r.referee_name AS arbitro, 
       r.dob          AS fecha_nacimiento
FROM       tb_match   AS m
INNER JOIN tb_team    AS l ON m.visitor_team_code = l.team_code
INNER JOIN tb_team    AS v ON m.visitor_team_code = v.team_code
INNER JOIN tb_referee AS r ON m.referee_code      = r.referee_code;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Luis!

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha servido, recuerda aceptarla y eventualmente darle al +1, es la forma "oficial" de decir Gracias! en Stack Overflow en español, además haces que el contenido perdure y pueda ayudar a otros usuarios.